# one comma or double comma?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> Also, sometimes, I cry.
>
> Also, sometimes I cry.

The safe answer is the former, but I am not sure if both are ok. What are the grammar rules on this?

> Also, sometimes I just keep running.
>
> Also, sometimes, I just keep running.

Comment: Doesn't the double coma add emphasis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form with and without the comma are both reasonable.  I'd apply the "If in doubt, leave it out" principle.

I'd actually prefer

> Also I sometimes cry.

The "just keep running" example is rather overloaded with adverbs. It should probably be rephrased in context, but the exact form of words depends on the context.

Comment: Both reasonable, but not at all the same meaning. I disagree that leaving the comma out is an acceptable alternative, whether you rearrange the sentence or not.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the second comma changes the emphasis of the sentence.

In the first sentence

> Also, sometimes, I cry

"sometimes" is a parenthetical clause, set off by parenthetical commas. You could take it out and the base sentence is unchanged: **Also I cry.** The "sometimes" is additional information.

In the second sentence

> Also, sometimes I cry

the base has changed; now **sometimes I cry** is the base sentence, and "Also" is the parenthetical remark. Because it is at the beginning of the sentence the first comma in the parenthetical-comma pair is hidden, but it is a parenthetical clause all the same.

So: in the first sentence, that fact that you also cry is the main idea, with the added information that you also cry *sometimes*, not all the time. In the second sentence it is reversed: the fact that you sometimes cry is the main information, and the fact that this is in addition to something else (perhaps someone else crying, or perhaps a different emotional response you have) is the added information.

It seems unnatural and incorrect to write the sentence with no commas at all.

Note that there is a third permutation possible:

> Sometimes I, also, cry.

which means more explicitly that you cry in addition to someone else crying. This sentence, unlike the others, would sound natural with or without the two commas (but you must use either both commas or none).